# How to insert export line bashrc with Makefile

Tags: makefile

I would like to insert the following line in my .bashrc file through Makefile

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to add a line to your .bashrc as part of a Makefile rule? You'd do that the same way you add the line to your .bashrc when _not_ in a Makefile :)

Comment: @user5628623  this is not the right thing to do with a makefile.  Do it with a shell script.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Yes I was also searching to include shell script in a Makefile.

Comment: @thepaul No, But what if others want to set up my code in their environment.

Comment: You can invoke a shell script in a makefile, you can even translate a shell script into a makefile, but I think @MarkGaleck meant that a makefile is not the right tool for this job. You can drive a nail with a wrench, but you shouldn't, nor should you drive a nail with a hammer held in a wrench.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using command:

```
@echo export PATH=$(HOME)/.rbenv/bin:$(PATH) >> ~/bashrc
```